# rails how to render a page which is from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am trying to render a view from one page to another pager that

I want render companyratings/show in pages/companies_list. So I have used the following code to do that

in companies_list.html.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'companyratings/show' %>
```

but it showing an error in my companyrating/show 
page
NoMethodError in Pages#companies_list

```
at undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

this my content in my companyratings/show

```
<title>Shared Todo App </title>
<h1>Shared Todo App</h1>
<p>All your todos here</p>
<table border="3">                         
  <tr>                          
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>place</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
    <th>Rank</th>
  </tr>
<% @companies.each do |companies| %>     
  <tr>
    <td>  <%= companies.name%> </td>  
    <td><%= companies.place%></td> 
    <td><%= companies.rate%>%</td> 
    <td><%= companies.rank%></td>  
  </tr>
<% end %>                        
</table>
```

this is my companies_list file

```
<% if signed_in? %>
  <div class="row">
    <aside class="span4">
     <section>
                   <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
 <%= render :partial => 'companyratings/show' %>

      </section>

  </div>  
<% else %>
<%end%>
```

Here is the controller for companyratings

```
class CompanyratingsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
    before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy


def index
     @companies = Companyrating.all
     @companyrating = Companyrating.new

  end

def show
    @companyrating = Companyrating.new
    @companies = Companyrating.all
end



def create
  @companies = Companyrating.new(params[:companyrating])
  if @companies.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to My Space!"
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  else
    flash[:error] = "Can't create companyrating."
    render 'index'
  end
end


 private
 def new_company_rating
      params.require(:company_rating).permit(:name, :place, :rate, :rank, :user_id)
 end
def correct_user
      @companies = current_user.companies.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @companyrating.nil?
    end


end
```

this is my controller code for pages controller

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def companies_list
    @title = "companies_list"
    if signed_in?
       @companies_mines  = current_user.companies_mines.build



    end
  end


end
```

So can any one help how to do this

Comment: can you post a contents of your files?

Comment: Stacktrace would be helpful.

Comment: Hi I have posted the file. And please dont give negative rating. I know it is a simple problem but I am newbie right now I am learning. So please help me.

Comment: What's @companies set to? It's impossible to diagnose without any context.

Comment: I have posted my controllers code above

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by the fact, that you're probably not setting `@companies` variable in method responsible for rendering `companies_list` file.

We can't tell you anything more until you provide us controller code.

Comment: Are you sure that's all the relevant code? Those file names of your views seems to be a non-default ones. They should be `show.html.erb` and `index.html.erb` which let me think that your code samples lacks some info.

Comment: I just wanted to get only show.html.erb page to render in my companies_list.html.erb

Comment: Will changing `<%= render :partial => 'companyratings/show' %>` to `<%= render 'companyratings/show' %>` change anything?

Comment: No still the same. I have a doubt should I need to add anything to the pages-controller ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have `@companies` on hand and pass it along with `locals`. Then reference the local variable.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Look at 3.4.6 local variables

Answer (score 0):

your doing right way but for solved to that error you have to do some following changes.

as you have the `def companies_list`

in your page controller, here there is no instance for `@companies` as you have used in your partial('companyratings/show').

The error occurred because you are not sending any `@companies` as locales and you have used looping thought it.

so add @companies instance in def companies_list and send as locales into partial like this

```
<%= render :partial => 'companyratings/show', locals=>{:companies => @companies } %>
```

and use companies instance instead of @companies.

Comment: So clearly tell me what should I add in def companies_list controllers